# windows live: 'wl_auth' cookie has multiple values

Tags: api, live

I am trying to implement the code from this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/hh278354, but I am getting this error:

**[WL]The 'wl_auth' cookie has multiple values. Ensure that the redirect URI specifies a cookie domain and path when setting cookies.**

The code I'm calling is at this page http://www.mysite.com/Javascript.aspx and redirect URI is also pointing to this page. What is the problem, where do I need to specify cookie domain?